# Errors when installing from iOS app store on some devices

Tags: ios, app-store, ios-provisioning

On some iOS devices the following errors and warnings (among others) are logged during install of our app from the App Store.

```
Apr  3 12:13:45 My-iPhone AppStore[268] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Apr  3 12:14:28 My-iPhone installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ffda000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-4231485137084285600/7874227378640616565" requested by itunesstored
Apr  3 12:14:29 My-iPhone installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ffda000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.mydomain.myapp
Apr  3 12:14:29 My-iPhone installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ffda000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 1.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.30s; LS Sync: 0.02s; Overall: 1.33s
Apr  3 12:14:31 My-iPhone lockdownd[45] <Warning>: SSSQLiteDatabase: Could not setup database: [14, /var/root/Library/com.apple.itunesstored/kvs.sqlitedb]
Apr  3 12:14:39 My-iPhone awdd[799] <Error>: CoreLocation: CLClient is deprecated. Will be obsolete soon.
```

Our current theory is that this is related to a runtime problem that our app is having on  these devices. When the exact same binary is installed as an ad hoc IPA the runtime problem does not occur. On devices that do not exhibit the runtime problem the above error messages are not logged during install from the App Store.

As for the runtime problem, we do not know exactly what happens as it is not possible to debug the app. We have a hunch that it may be access to the keychain that fails and that it could be related to entitlements, but this is just a hunch and could very well be wrong.

Is there anything in the app itself that could be causing this or should we write this off as a system problem and advice users with this problem to restore their devices?

Any input greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen those crash issues with frameworks and iOS6 but without more details of what you are using it's hard to say what's causing the issue. If I had to guess I would say this is a memory related issue. Try to track down if the users having the issues are also the users that have little memory space left. It may also be resident memory causing the issue so a fresh reboot would be a good thing to try as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Rebooting does not help. Do you mean that it runs out of memory during the installation?